# SqlAlchemy - Selecting specific column in Model

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy for a small meal planning project in python. I have the following models set up:

```
class ScheduedRecipe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    recipe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id'))
    recipe = db.relationship('Recipe')
    scheduled_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    meal = db.Column(db.String)


class Recipe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    procedure = db.Column(db.Text)
    preptime = db.Column(db.Text)
    waittime = db.Column(db.Text)
    cooktime = db.Column(db.Text)
    ingredients = db.relationship('RecipeIngredient')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Recipe: {}>'.format(self.name)
```

When I run ScheduledRecipe.query.get(id), recipe is the whole object from the Recipe model (as expected), but I'd like to only return the name. Is it possible using this structure, or do I have to manually query the database, and skip adding the relationship in ScheduledRecipe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you shoud refer to relationship in sqlalchemy https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Yeah I did, it doesn't look like it mentions a way to isolate a single column though, and it just sends over the whole object from what I can see.